# Embed a video with slides beside

Tags: html, flash, frontend

Like http://videolectures.net/ijcai2011_koller_scene/

The display of video and slides can be adjusted. Is it implemented using html or video cutting?

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented using flash by adobe.